# How to disable forward ref in react link?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using `Link` component in react, and it does something weird.

[image]

it appends my path `"requests"` to something called children and results in a different url `"/requests/requests"`

But I want it to be only `"/requests" not "/requests/requests"

That's my code:

```
<Link key={i + singleCrumb.path} to={singleCrumb.path}>
  {singleCrumb.label + '/'}
</Link>
```

`singleCrumb.label` has a string that should be my label.
`singleCrumb.path` has a string that should be my path.

Comment: What is the value in `singleCrumb.path` ?

Comment: a single string "requests" to be put in the url for routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.forwardRef` isn't the issue here; forwarding React refs only passes, i.e. forwards, any React refs ***your code*** creates to the `Link` component to be used by the `Link`. Your code isn't passing any React refs though.

It appears you are passing a relative path (*versus an absolute path*) to the `Link` component's `to` prop. The difference between relative and absolute routing/navigation is a leading `"/"` character. Absolute paths start with a leading `"/"` character, relative paths ***do not***. In the React dev tools you can see that the `Link`'s `to` prop value is `"requests"`, so this is treated as a link to a route *relative* to the current location, i.e. `pathname` and is appended to the end of the path.

To resolve it seems like you should prepend the `"/"` character to make this an absolute path. Make the link target `"/requests"` instead of `"requests"` (*`"requests"` resolving to `"/requests/requests"`*).

Example:

```
<Link key={`/${singleCrumb.path}`} to={`/${singleCrumb.path}`}>
  {singleCrumb.label + '/'}
</Link>
```

Comment: i want it to be resolved to "/requests" only not "/requests/requests" nor "requests/requests"

Comment: @Abdel-Rahman That's exactly what the code above should resolve for you.